# what does clip do? when they using it for test set

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

my X_test is shape with (214200, 35) 
and I don't understand what clip does for this line of code

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test).clip(0., 20.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given an interval, values outside the interval are clipped to the interval edges. For example, if an interval of `[0, 1]` is specified, values smaller than 0 become 0, and values larger than 1 become 1.

If you are predicting something and want to clip the prediction results to interval edges then you will be using `.clip`.

Example

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> np.clip(a, 1, 8)
array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8])
```

[Reference : numpy.clip](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)

Answer (score 1):

The clip() is a numpy method that is used to limit the values in an array. Say you have a numpy array `x = [1,2,4,6,5,6,9]` and you want to limit the values in that array between 1 and 5. Then you would use`x.clip(1,5)` that will give an output `[1,2,4,5,5,5,5]`. The values greater than 5 are clipped down to 5.

In your code the output array of `model.predict(X_test)` will be clipped from 0 to 20. So, all the values in `y_pred` will lie between 0 and 20.